# What does this definition of a Weyl star algebra in Spectral theory and QM by Moretti, 2013 mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, definition

I don't understand the words in boldface:

> Definition 11.25 Let $X$ be a (non-trivial) real vector space of arbitrary dimension (possibly infinite) and $\sigma : X \times X \to R$ a symplectic form on it. A star algebra $W(X, \sigma)$ is called Weyl star algebra of $(X, \sigma)$ if there exists a family $\{W(u)\}_{ u \in X}$ of non-zero elements called the generators, such that:
>
> (i) Weyl's commutation relations: $W(u)W(v) = e^{(-i/2) \sigma (u, v)} W(u + v), W^*(u) = W(-u)$
>
> (ii)$W(x,\sigma)$ is generated by $\{W(u)\}_{u \in X}$, i.e. it coincides with the linear span **of finite combinations** of finite products of  $\{W(u)\}_{u \in X}$

If those words weren't there, I would understand the definition to mean that each element of the star algebra can be expressed as a finite linear combination of products of elements in $\{W(u)\}_{u \in X}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the interpretation is the one you wrote. I understand that the sentence is quite cumbersome as it stands, it seems a superposition of two sentences, I am sorry. "the linear span of" should read "the set of".  I do not know if, in  the 2018 edition, that sentence was improved.